# Referenced posts redirect back to the referencing question #241173 in its answers #241190 & #241180

Tags: support

I found a strange behavior regarding the links referencing other posts in

[How are “/dev” Linux files created?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241173/how-are-dev-linux-files-created/241176)

- In kasperd's answer

  > One previous answer has **[many details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241176/68601)** about that, which I am not going to repeat.
- And in Basile Starynkevitch's answer

  > In addition of device nodes explained in other answers (created with mknod(2) or supplied by some devfs), notably the **[one from Sepahrad Salour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241176/50557)**, [...]

Both links lead back to the referencing post "How are “/dev” Linux files created?".

What's wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: And yes, I've tried turning my computer off and on again. :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer that's linked to here is now deleted, since it was just a copy-paste of [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file). I fixed the answers to point to that article instead.

Comment: Thanks, I had deleted the plagiarized answer but hadn't noticed it was referenced in another.